# Is it possible to alter the column familes of a column in hbase?

Tags: hbase

For example:

```
row1,cf1:a,cf2:b
row2,cf1:x,cf1:y 
row3,cf2:a,cf2:c
```

`row1` is the row key of my table and `cf1` and `cf2` are the column families. I would like to move the column `cf1:a` from `row1` to `cf2:a`. i.e. change its column family. Is it possible to change it directly without deleting the row and then put it into the new family?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hbase stores data in hfiles with column family names, because of that you can not move columns between families without delete/put, i think. If there was a shell command for that, it would do the same for you.

I think you should think how do you do this if you table is huge :)
Maybe coprocessors can help, in theory they process data in hbase region server where it stored, so you can avoid network transfer and do the migration on multiple server simultaneously.

If your table is small in size (like less than 10 million), just write a java code, reads rows one by one from a Scan result, and delete&put column key to other family. Don't forget to use a column key selector in Scan. I mean get only that column from database to your program.